# Callback method only get called when debugger is attached

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm writing an Android app which connects to an BLE device and shows the end result of the measurement. I'm using a library of the company for communicating with the device and the problem I have is that the callback functions (onMeasurementFinished,onMeasurementFailed, etc.) only get called if I set a breakpoint and run the app with a debugger attached.

Here is how I connect to the device:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            if (view.getId() == R.id.btnConnect) {
                deviceArm.scan(this, this);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

This is the callback of the scan that is working:

```
 @Override
    public void onDeviceConnected() {
        txtResults.setText("Connected");
        deviceArm.startMeasurement(this);
    }
```

These are the callbacks of startMeasurement that only work if I debug:

```
@Override
public void onMeasurementError(Error error) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            txtResults.setText("Error");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onMeasurementFinished(MeasurementType measurementType, final Object o) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           txtResults.setText("Finished"+o.toString());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onMeasurementStarted() {

}

@Override
public void onMeasurementProgress(final MeasurementType measurementType, final Object o) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            txtResults.setText(o.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

I know it's not much information but I can only hope that mabey some of you have an **idea** what the problem could be.

Comment: Without knowing what the interface does it is hard for us to estimate what is the problem. You need to share more, like what the startMeasurement does, some code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's likely happening is the peripheral device is doing some extra setup after connection. So putting a breakpoints in onDeviceConnected gives it time to do this.

As you say, not much information to go on, but it's possible the peripheral is sending the measurement results via notification/indication. So the peripheral needs time to configure these before starting measurments.

Try adding a delay in onDeviceConnected before starting the measurment. Ideally your library will have a callback along the lines of onDeviceReady, that you could use instead.